# Filtered Search in Rails 4 using ActiveRecord Querying Interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model-view-controller

I have some filters in place when performing a search. I have another search filter that I am trying to implement, but can't seem to get it to work. I am having issues with the first_name last_name and building the view for that.

Controller:

```
if params[:address_search]
   @payment_requests = @payment_requests.where('full_address ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:address_search]}%")

   unless params[:unit_search].blank?
      @payment_requests = @payment_requests.where('unit ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:unit_search]}%")
   end
elsif params[:client_search]
   @payment_requests = @payment_requests.where('email ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:client_search]}%")
elsif params[:first_name] || params[:last_name]
   @payment_requests = PaymentRequest.includes(:detail).where(payment_details: { first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name]})
   end
else
   @payment_requests = @payment_requests.active
end
```

Views:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= text_field_tag 'client_search', '', id: 'pay-client-search', placeholder: 'Email Search', class: 'general-text-area pay-filter' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
key = "%#{search_text}%"

@payment_requests = PaymentRequest.joins(:detail).where('payment_details.first_name LIKE :search OR payment_details.last_name LIKE :search', search: key)
```

P.S: Not tried this.

Comment: Does the key = "%#{search_text}%" go in the view?

Comment: No. It should be in controller. search_text should be replaced by your variable name. Ex: key = "%#{params[:first_name]}%"